# How to put tikzpicture aligned with the footerline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I would like to put a tikzpicture near the footer line. The tikzpicture is used to show the page number on top of an image. The problem i am having is the tikzpicture is centered on the footer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\definecolor{light-blue}{RGB}{0,175,236}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0in} % Ajust the header/footer width with the set margins.
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{light-blue}%
   \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
   \hrule width\headwidth height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}

\rfoot{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.297in,height=0.353in]{pagenumber.png}};
\node[align=center,white] at (image.center) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=1.5in,right=0.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works as expected once a typo in `\includegraphics` is fixed (there was a missing opening brace before the name of the image file); using `xshift` and `yshift` you can fine tune the `\node` position:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=1.5in,right=0.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\definecolor{light-blue}{RGB}{0,175,236}

\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{light-blue}%
   \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
   \hrule width\headwidth height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[xshift=-0.1485in,yshift=2pt] (image) {\includegraphics[width=0.297in,height=0.353in]{pagenumber.png}};
  \node[align=center,white] at (image.center) {\thepage};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

An image of the bottom right corner of the page and showing the desired result:

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Yes, i have missed the { in the image. But my concern is i want the image next to the footer line. For example, i want to align the top of the black rectangle on the footer line. how can i achieve that?

Comment: @Pete what footer line? Your code doesn't produce a physical line; I don't understand what line are you referring to.

Comment: I have edited my 1st post and it includes the footer line. sorry, i thought it was there by default.

Comment: @Pete I updated my answer.